# overshoot pose from robot_localization

Tags: navigation, odometry, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I'd like to seek your support in running robot_localization. here is my current configuration.

**ODOM Source:** iRobotcreate2 using [autonomy_create](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy) driver
publishing `odom->base_link` at 50Hz,  frame_id = `odom`  child_frame_id = `base_link`

**IMU Source:** LPMS USBAL2 using [lpms_imu](https://github.com/larics/lpms_imu) from larics
publishing `/imu_data` topic at 50Hz,
frame_id = `base_link`

```
  <node name="robot_localization" pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" clear_params="true" output="screen" >
```

**robot_localization launch**

```
  <param name="frequency" value="50"/>

  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.1"/>

  <param name="odom0" value="/odom"/>
  <param name="imu0" value="/imu_data"/>

  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
  <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>
  <param name="two_d_mod" value="true"/>
  <param name="publish_tf" value="false"/>

  <rosparam param="odom0_config">[false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  true, true, false,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false]</rosparam>

  <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false,
                                 false, false, true,
                                 false, false, false,
                                 false, false, false,
                                 false, false, false]</rosparam>

  <param name="odom0_queue_size" value="10"/>
  <param name="imu0_queue_size" value="10"/>

  <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="false"/>
  <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
  <param name="imu0_differential" value="false"/>

  <rosparam param="process_noise_covariance">[0.03, 0,    0,   0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0.03, 0,   0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0.4, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,   0.03, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,   0,    0.03, 0,    0,     0,     0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,   0,    0,    0.06, 0,     0,     0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,   0,    0,    0,    0.025, 0,     0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,   0,    0,    0,    0,     0.025, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,   0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.05, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,   0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.002, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,   0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,     0.002, 0,     0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,   0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,     0,     0.004, 0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,   0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,     0,     0,     0.01, 0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,   0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0.01, 0,
                                              0,    0,    0,   0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0.01]</rosparam>

  <rosparam param="initial_estimate_covariance">[1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                 0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                 0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                 0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                 0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,  0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,    0,
                                                 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9, 0,    0,
                                                 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9, 0,
                                                 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]</rosparam>

</node>
```

Problem:

when i move the robot slightly forward around 10cm, my robot localization output is like this
My current expectation robot_localization filter output will not move tremendously 5meters

```
header: 
  seq: 1113
  stamp: 
    secs: 1507602484
    nsecs: 702803612
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 5.2929843497
      y: -0.375213039163
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0167304031319
      w: 0.999860037011
  covariance: [0.6681722616323746, 2.906207020757163e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.1489494825382577e-10, 2.9062070207844828e-05, 0.6685898434755646, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.7353167974823654e-08, 0.0, 0.0, 3078.1527164512236, -0.8299654789702702, -34.08684051036556, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.8299654789702722, 8.014619379485639, -3.2526065174565133e-18, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -34.08684051036563, -9.242823520438925e-18, 8.014619379485637, 0.0, -3.1489494825382107e-10, -4.7353167974823614e-08, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0006098784807259002]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: -0.00573980186551
      y: 2.42841858036e-06
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0191862965923
  covariance: [0.00050634837712305, 1.2946270499593127e-13, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.2946270976708657e-13, 0.0005063483541373269, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 37.90151702124765, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04453793530328407, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04453793530328407, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.015551912176054818]
```

/odom topic output

```
header: 
  seq: 1130
  stamp: 
    secs: 1507602485
    nsecs:    836908
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.0835771486163
      y: 0.000380135315936
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.00189176298531
      w: 0.999998210615
  covariance: [0.04401147738099098, 0.00010810681851580739, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0012149321846663952, 0.00010810676758410409, 0.0074375285767018795, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.13262373208999634, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0012149312533438206, 0.13262373208999634, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.1878230571746826]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0. 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I have uploaded my [bagfile](https://github.com/fj138696/ros_question/blob/master/robot_localization_velocity1.bag.tar.gz) with all recorded topics. This robot_localization configuration is basically i patterned using the sample [test2.bag](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/tree/kinetic-devel/test) from robot_localization package.

i am hoping someone can help me figure out what is wrong in any of my configuration. You're support is very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272642/overshoot-pose-from-robot_localization/) by [fj138696](https://answers.ros.org/users/30352/fj138696/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2017-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pose is moving rapidly because your X velocity data is extremely large. This is from your `odom` data, presumably from `autonomy_create`.

```
header: 
  seq: 934
  stamp: 
    secs: 1507602481
    nsecs:  80840055
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.0602380000055
      y: 0.00023190813954
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.000945881799379
      w: 0.999999552654
  covariance: [0.03145275264978409, 7.371223910013214e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.003105021081864834, 7.371225365204737e-05, 0.002794417552649975, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06957972049713135, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, -0.0031050220131874084, 0.06957972049713135, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.2781670093536377]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 4.96720266342
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.00044456301839090884, 8.409973020206962e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.7008354663848877e-08, 8.409971883338585e-07, 7.954953140654197e-09, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.4315063708636444e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, -2.7124769985675812e-08, 1.4315063708636444e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03220024332404137]
```

Look at `twist/twist/linear/x`. See how it's approximately 5? The units are meters per second for velocities, so the EKF thinks your robot is going at 5 m/s. I'd check the source code for the `autonomy_create` package, if that's what's generating this message.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0